# Can I get the metadata about the themes in Oracle MapViewer?

Tags: oracle-dbms

I am trying to use the MapViewer xml api to generate a dynamic theme (for generic highlighting support), but don't want to expose table names and such to users, I would like then to communicate in terms of themes.  Is there some way that I can obtain the mappings from theme to table so that I can generate dynamic themes based on `jdbc_query` element?

The `jdbc_query` needs me to give it some SQL which identifies the instances to be included in the dynamic theme.  I want the user to be able to specify a theme name and then be able to construct an sql statement which gets the geometry of the nearest neighbour to a particular point on that theme.  To do this I need to know which table the data in the theme came from and which column contains the geometry in that table.

Can I find that information using an `info_request` perhaps?